# html5boiler plate + jquery mobile = scripts loading twice

Tags: jquery, mobile, html5boilerplate

I am working on an experimental jquery mobile based app using [html5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) as a base for html and such.

Basically all I have done thus far is:

1. Download and extract html5 boilerplate, and view it in the browser. Make sure scripts/styles are loading properly. Good ready to go.
2. Add jquery mobile (cdn hosted full version 1.0 [released today? right on!])
3. Add `$(document).ready(function () { console.log('ready'); });`
4. Reload. 'ready' is output twice.. the second one after a slight delay..
5. wtf bbq and such inspect situation in chrome inspector.. notice all javascript files seem to be loading twice.
6. Restart from scratch, extract h5bp load in browser, note in particular that scripts load once. Add document ready handler, observe one output of 'ready'.
7. Add jquery mobile observe scripts loading once.
8. Move all scripts into the  tag. Scripts load once.

Anyone have any idea what is going on? It should be pretty easy to reproduce this, just extract h5bp and add jquery mobile to the scripts section at the bottom and suddenly the scripts all are loading twice. Move all those scripts into the head tag beneath (or before) modernizr and this no longer occurs.

Thanks

Comment: Dunno but I would just start deleting code. It could be some fakebody trick that JQM, JQ and Modernizr disagree on. Just reduce your test case more and more until you find the conflict

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into fake body.

Answer (score 3):

Modernizr uses YepNope to load scripts. If you take a look at the issue here: https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js/issues/10

you'll see that scripts are intentionally loaded twice:

> Yepnope does request every file you put into it twice. The first time
>   it loads itself into your cache as some sort of non-executable entity
>   (an object element, or an img element, or a script element with a fake
>   type attribute, depending on your browser). The second time it's
>   injected, we inject it as an executable script, and this time it's
>   cached. So there is really only the millisecond or less that it takes
>   to execute the callback function and reinject a script tag extra (and
>   however long it takes to access the cache).

There's also mention of this on the http://yepnopejs.com home page. Just go there and scroll down to `I'm seeing two requests in my dev tools, why is it loading everything twice?`

Comment: I think you need to read my post carefully. I am aware of the behavior of yepnope, the issue is that with jquerymobile added, event handlers and such are actually executing twice. The scripts are also loaded twice according to the Network pane of the inspector WITH jqM, but not without it.

Comment: Fair enough. But if you'll read the paragraph on the yepnope page that I referred you to, it says that if you are seeing double load times, then you need to make sure you're sending the correct cache headers. If yepnope can't cache the first load, then you would get double executes.

Comment: Just re reading old comments - Did not intend to come off in the manner in which it sounds that I did. Belated thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

Putting your `<script>document.ready()</script>` in `<head></head>` will fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using $(document).ready()??

Ran into this same issue and was frustrated to no end, noticed that if I moved all the JS to the head of the document it worked fine. When I switched everything to use pageinit started working properly with JS at bottom of page where it belongs.

example:

```
<div id="mainPage" data-role="page">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#project_map_page").live('pageinit', function() {
        // INSERT JS HERE
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

further details available at: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html

Comment: this did not helped me :(

Comment: might have changed -- this answer is over 2 years old =)

Comment: Oh too bad I tried almost all the possibilities still not able to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding jQuery and jQuery Mobile on a basic html page, it seems to happen like this as well. So don't think it's h5bp related. Could you try strip out the h5bp stuff and load again?

Comment: Interesting, I'll try adding only jquery and jqM to a simple html5 page.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your root div is like this...

```
<body>
<div data-role="page">
 <!-- Content -->
</div>
</body>
```